# Output from InputStream hangs after last line

Tags: java

I have a requirement to check for the status of a job till it is success. For this I have written the following code.
But the programs hangs after last while statement is executed.

```
boolean isComplete = false;
            for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
                p_stdin.write("ar job-name");
                p_stdin.newLine();
                p_stdin.flush();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                Scanner s = new Scanner( p.getInputStream() );
                String output = "";
                while (s.hasNext())
                {
                    output = s.next() ;
                    System.out.println(output);
                    if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("SU")) {
                        isComplete = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(isComplete) {
                    System.out.println("Found");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found in "+ i + " iteration");
                }
                s.close();
            }
```

Comment: Any chance the output isn't exactly equal to `SU`, i.e. could there be some whitespace in the string? Do you even get that string? The problem is that `Scanner.hasNext()` (as the JavaDoc states) will block and wait for input, i.e. it will wait for `SU`.

Comment: Before the if statement, the syso prints all the lines. I can see that it completely loops through the commandline screen. But immediately after the last line is printed, program hangs

Comment: Yes but in case there is no `SU` line the scanner will wait for more. It doesn't know whether the input stream is done or just takes a little to produce new input.

Comment: There is good chance that `SU` wont be there in first for loop iteration. That is why I keep looping for till `SU` is returned

Comment: Your code indicates that `SU` might not be sent at all, i.e. you only set `isComplete = true` if you find it and _after_ the loop check whether you found it or not. However, the while-loop won't end until you get `SU` (case-insensitive but otherwise it needs to be _exact_) so if that never occurs the _while_ loop won't end. So your input _needs_ to send some EOF signal, be it some char sequence, a null terminator, etc.

Comment: While loop will iterate till scanner has a next element. It is working. But now it is executing the for loop twice and gives me the following error
`Not found in 0 iteration
Not found in 1 iteration
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()):

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. *This method may block while waiting for input to scan*. The scanner does not advance past any input.

You need to close the stream you have written to so that `hasNext()` has a chance to return `false`.

Comment: I am getting the following exception if I close the stream. `java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed`